# Run wordpress code from command prompt via PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, command-line

I need to run custom WP script from command line :  php myscript.php
Whatever I do it doesn't work.  I get this message:

**Error establishing a database connection**

I tried

```
define('DOING_AJAX', true);
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
$_SERVER = array(
    "HTTP_HOST" => "mysite.com",
    "SERVER_NAME" => "mysite.com",
    "REQUEST_URI" => "/myscript.php",
    "REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"
);
require_once('wp-load.php');
```

mentioned [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5349/access-wordpress-api-outside-of-wordpress-command-line-php) but it doesn't work. All server variables set by me are OK, I copied the whole $_SERVER variable from web page launched in browser (there it works)

My working directory is the root of the WP install so I simply use: **php myscript.php**
from command line.
I tried several other codes mentioned on net but non of them works for me.
e.g the one with :

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-blog-header.php');
```

Always the same message:  **Error establishing a database connection**
As I said from web browser it works OK.

This is the extraction of mysql strings from php.ini used by php cli:

```
Configure Command =>  '/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53.3.1~2/php/configure'  '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--sysconfdir=/private/etc' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--enable-cli' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-kerberos=/usr' '--with-zlib=/usr' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--enable-calendar' '--with-curl=/usr' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53.3.1~2/Root/usr/local' '--with-png-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53.3.1~2/Root/usr/local' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-ldap=/usr' '--with-ldap-sasl=/usr' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-iodbc=/usr' '--enable-shmop' '--with-snmp=/usr' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-iconv-dir=/usr' '--with-xsl=/usr' '--enable-zend-multibyte' '--enable-zip' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr'
mysql
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533 $
mysql.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysql.allow_persistent => On => On
mysql.connect_timeout => 60 => 60
mysql.default_host => no value => no value
mysql.default_password => no value => no value
mysql.default_port => no value => no value
mysql.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.default_user => no value => no value
mysql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode => Off => Off
mysqli
Client API library version => mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533 $
mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off
mysqlnd
mysqlnd => enabled
Version => mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533 $
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite, sqlite2
pdo_mysql
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533 $
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: You are using the cli version of PHP. Is MySQL enabled ?

Comment: php -ver
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Aug 22 2010 19:41:55) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

Comment: +1 keatch, check if mysql extension is enabled for cli. Check also error log. And are you executing this command on the server ? If not, may be your mysql server don't accept connection from outside.

Comment: Beside this, if your script works from your web server, why don't you use it like this ?

Comment: I edited post and added extraction of php.ini used by php cli. Seems to be enabled for me. I don't want to use it via wget or curl, just directly via php.

Comment: Have you actually configured your database in the wordpress config files?

Comment: I use it on local environment, it works Ok in browser.

Comment: Again, check your error log to get exact error message

Comment: If you are using this on local env, then it's probably what I said before : may be your mysql server don't accept connection from outside

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, first things to do :

- check error log to get more information on the error
- check php cli conf

And since you are executing this command from a local environnement, your mysql server probably don't accept connection from outside.

Comment: got it working:
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock 
It was wrong path to socket used by PHP CLI

Answer (score 0):

Got it working:

`sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock`

It was wrong path for socket used by PHP CLI

Answer (score 0):

The secret is that you defined the same names for the constants that WP uses. Change `DB_USER/DB_PASSWORD/DB_HOST` and everything's gonna be ok :D
(god, it took me two hours to find "the bug")

cheers!